# Convert pandas DataFrame to a 3d graph using Index and Columns as X,Y and values as Z?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a 3d volatlity surface with a Pandas Dataframe, I feel like I have all the information but I'm unsure how to create a 3d graph from this. Every guide I've read seems to use 3 separate arrays but I feel like the data I have should be graphable.

My current dataframe looks like this:

I would like my X values to be my index, the Y values to be the column names (the months) and the Z values to be the actual values contained in the frame (So as an example, the first value in the first row first column... X = 35, Y = 9/20/2019, Z = 0.0879441)

```
   09/20/2019   10/18/2019  11/15/2019  12/20/2019  01/17/2020
35  0.0879441   0.0883913   0.0909429   0.0987415   0.0987912
40  0.0833955   0.0837764   0.087088    0.0939974   0.0943858
45  0.0788468   0.0810964   0.084231    0.0905135   0.0912521
50  0.0766043   0.0784164   0.0820014   0.0891319   0.0871471
55  0.0743284   0.0744855   0.0757832   0.0729094   0.068998
60  0.0612799   0.0664453   0.0758287   0.0729539   0.0690739
65  0.0613116   0.0664716   0.0655504   0.0622985   0.0630833
```

After looking around I tried to imitate the code [here](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/04.12-three-dimensional-plotting.html): specifically in Cell 5 and 6. Here's my code below

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = my_dataframe.index

Y = my_dataframe.columns


def lookup(row, cols):
    return(my_dataframe.loc[x,y])

Z = lookup(x,y)


fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection = '3d')

ax.contour3D(X,Y,Z)
```

I basically defined Z as a function of X,Y hoping that would work, but to no avail I get an error saying:

```
Length of x must be number of columns in z
```

What am I doing wrong here? Fwiw I trued using the X,Y = np.meshgrid() as in the link but that didn't work either so I posted my original attempt.

EDIT: Upon suggestion from some of the comments I've changed my code to be like so:

```
Y = my_dataframe.index

my_dataframe.columns = [1,2,3,4,5]

X = my_dataframe.columns


Z = my_dataframe.values

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection = '3d')

ax.contour3D(X,Y, Z)
```

I changed the columns from dates to just numbers to ensure they were a numeric type. I also set Z equal to the values of the dataframe. I now get a new error:

```
 setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Comment: It should be `Z = dataframe.values`, the lookupdoes not make sense and `x` and `y` are not defined. However, `Y` must be of numeric type, not `10/18/2019`.

Comment: Oh, and actually you confused `X` and `Y`. `X` must be the columns, not `Y`.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest my bad on the X, Y. My real code I used slightly messy variable names so I tried to clean up the names before posting here, and I missed out on the capitalization. I tried it your way setting Z = dataframe.values. I also set the column names to just be numbers (1,2,3,4,5) and now I get a new error: setting an array element with a sequence. I'm not entirely sure what this means, I'm looking around and I'm starting to think maybe it's just not possible to graph a 3d map with the data the way I have it

Comment: It's sure possible. You will need to create a grid of values though, `X, Y = np.meshgrid(X,Y)`

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest YO!!!!! That worked. Thanks so much! I'm a bit confused about one thing still though, why did I have to switch X and Y? I'm super confused why that was an issue

Comment: X is the columns, Y is the rows.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for:

[Run the code on google colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Nnxxemtuq_TIrL0iIcT7ZxpGYXD1JFrf?usp=sharing)

```
import pandas as pd
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d = {10: [1, 2], 20: [3, 4]}
my_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
#  10  20
#  ------
#0  1   3
#1  2   4

X = my_dataframe.index

Y = my_dataframe.columns

Z = my_dataframe.values


fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection = '3d')

ax.contour3D(X,Y,Z)
```

Comment: unfortunately I'm getting a new error when I set  Z = my_dataframe.values it gives me an error saying: setting an array element with a sequence.

Comment: What is the type of your index, columns, and values? They should not be strings for the plot.

Comment: hmm I converted them all to numbers, so I don't think we have a problem there

Comment: Have you converted the name of the columns to numbers too? Maybe that is the issue! Please copy your code here if doesn't work.

Comment: The above code does not output any result.

Comment: Just tried running it on an online compiler. Is this the error you get? "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mpl_toolkits'"

Comment: This code works fine on google colab: