# How do I make a make a simple contour chart of a Pandas DataFrame with numeric cell values as Z and labeled rows/columns as X and Y coordinates?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, charts, 3d

I have a Pandas DataFrame, `luminance_df`, that looks like this:

|  | barelyvisible | ultralight | light | abitlight | medium | abitdark | dark | evendarker | ultradark | almostblack |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| orange | 96 | 92 | 83 | 72 | 61 | 53 | 48 | 40 | 34 | 28 |
| gold | 96 | 89 | 77 | 65 | 56 | 50 | 44 | 37 | 31 | 26 |
| yellow | 95 | 88 | 77 | 64 | 53 | 47 | 40 | 33 | 29 | 26 |
| chartreuse | 95 | 89 | 80 | 67 | 55 | 44 | 35 | 27 | 23 | 20 |
| green | 97 | 93 | 85 | 73 | 58 | 45 | 36 | 29 | 24 | 20 |
| forest | 96 | 90 | 80 | 67 | 52 | 39 | 30 | 24 | 20 | 16 |
| aqua | 97 | 89 | 78 | 64 | 50 | 40 | 32 | 26 | 22 | 19 |
| teal | 96 | 90 | 82 | 69 | 53 | 43 | 36 | 31 | 27 | 24 |
| lightblue | 97 | 94 | 86 | 74 | 60 | 48 | 39 | 32 | 27 | 24 |
| blue | 97 | 93 | 87 | 78 | 68 | 60 | 53 | 48 | 40 | 33 |
| indigo | 97 | 94 | 89 | 82 | 74 | 67 | 59 | 51 | 41 | 34 |
| purple | 98 | 95 | 92 | 85 | 76 | 66 | 58 | 50 | 42 | 35 |
| royalpurple | 98 | 95 | 92 | 85 | 75 | 65 | 56 | 47 | 39 | 32 |
| magenta | 98 | 95 | 91 | 83 | 73 | 61 | 49 | 40 | 33 | 28 |
| pink | 97 | 95 | 90 | 82 | 70 | 60 | 51 | 42 | 35 | 30 |
| dustypink | 97 | 95 | 90 | 82 | 71 | 60 | 50 | 41 | 35 | 30 |
| red | 97 | 94 | 89 | 82 | 71 | 60 | 51 | 42 | 35 | 31 |

So far, I'm building a single multi-chart HTML file like this:

```py
with open(os.path.join(cwd, 'testout.html'), 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write("<p>&nbsp;</p><hr/><p>&nbsp;</p>".join(['<h1>Colors</h1>'+hex_styler.to_html(), '<h1>Hue</h1>'+hue_styler.to_html(), '<h1>Saturation</h1>'+saturation_styler.to_html(
    ), '<h1>Luminance</h1>'+luminance_styler.to_html(), '<h1>Perceived Brightness</h1>'+perceived_brightness_pivot_styler.to_html(), '<h1>Base Data</h1>'+basic_df.to_html()]))
```

I'd like to display an elevation/contour style map of the Luminance right after `luminance_styler.to_html()`, a lot like this one that I produced in Excel:

[image: Luminance contour chart from Excel]

I'd like the colors to stay sorted "top to bottom" as values on a y-axis and the darknesses to stay sorted "left to right" as values on an x-axis, just like in the example above.

## Question

I'm not a data scientist, nor do I use Python terribly regularly.  I'm proud of myself for having made `luminance_df` in the first place, but I am not, for the life of me, figuring out how to make Python simply ... treat numeric cell values in a DataFrame whose labels in both directions are strings ... as a z-axis and make a contour-chart of it.

Everything I Google leads to really complicated data science nuanced questions.

**Could someone get me on the right track by giving me the basic "hello world" code to get at least as far with `luminance_df`'s data in Python as I got with the "insert chart" button in Excel?**

If you can get me so I've got a `img = BytesIO()` that's `image_base64 = base64.b64encode(img.read()).decode("utf-8")`-able, I can `f'<img src="data:image/png;base64, {image_base64}" />'` it myself into the string concatenation that makes `testout.html`.

I'm on Windows and have myself set up to be able to `pip install`.

## Notes

1. To be fair, I find these contour charts much more attractive and much easier to read than the one Excel made, but I'm fine with something sort of "brutish"-looking like the Excel version, as long as it makes "rising" & "falling" obvious and as long as it uses a ROYIGBV rainbow to indicate "less" vs. "more" *(pet peeve of mine about the default Excel colors -- yes, I know, it's probably an accessibility thing)*:

   [image: Rainbow contour chart]

   [image: Another rainbow contour chart]

   [image: Yet another rainbow contour chart]
2. While I'd like my chart's colors to follow a "rainbow" of sorts *(because personally I find them easy to read)*, any "rainbow shading" on the chart should completely ignore the fact that the labels of the y-axis happen to describe colors.  No correlation whatsoever.  I'm simply plotting number facts between 16 and 98; colors of the chart should just indicate the change in "elevation" between those two extremes.

## Effort so far

The only other "simple" question I've found so far that seems similar is [Convert pandas DataFrame to a 3d graph using Index and Columns as X,Y and values as Z?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57667213/convert-pandas-dataframe-to-a-3d-graph-using-index-and-columns-as-x-y-and-values), but this code didn't work for me at all, so I don't even know what it outputs, visually, so I have no idea if it's even relevant:

```py
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
lumX = luminance_df.columns
lumY = luminance_df.index
lumZ = luminance_df.values
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection = '3d')
ax.contour3D(lumX,lumY,lumZ)
```

My script errored out with a message:  `ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'orange'`, and I don't know what I'm doing enough to accommodate for the fact that this answer seems to have been written around a presumption of numeric X- and Y-axis keys.  *(Also, it might not generate the type of chart I'm hoping for -- as I said, can't tell because it doesn't even execute and there's no visual sample in the answer.)*

## Dataset

Ready for `pandas.DataFrame()`:

```json
{"barelyvisible":{"orange":96,"gold":96,"yellow":95,"chartreuse":95,"green":97,"forest":96,"aqua":97,"teal":96,"lightblue":97,"blue":97,"indigo":97,"purple":98,"royalpurple":98,"magenta":98,"pink":97,"dustypink":97,"red":97},"ultralight":{"orange":92,"gold":89,"yellow":88,"chartreuse":89,"green":93,"forest":90,"aqua":89,"teal":90,"lightblue":94,"blue":93,"indigo":94,"purple":95,"royalpurple":95,"magenta":95,"pink":95,"dustypink":95,"red":94},"light":{"orange":83,"gold":77,"yellow":77,"chartreuse":80,"green":85,"forest":80,"aqua":78,"teal":82,"lightblue":86,"blue":87,"indigo":89,"purple":92,"royalpurple":92,"magenta":91,"pink":90,"dustypink":90,"red":89},"abitlight":{"orange":72,"gold":65,"yellow":64,"chartreuse":67,"green":73,"forest":67,"aqua":64,"teal":69,"lightblue":74,"blue":78,"indigo":82,"purple":85,"royalpurple":85,"magenta":83,"pink":82,"dustypink":82,"red":82},"medium":{"orange":61,"gold":56,"yellow":53,"chartreuse":55,"green":58,"forest":52,"aqua":50,"teal":53,"lightblue":60,"blue":68,"indigo":74,"purple":76,"royalpurple":75,"magenta":73,"pink":70,"dustypink":71,"red":71},"abitdark":{"orange":53,"gold":50,"yellow":47,"chartreuse":44,"green":45,"forest":39,"aqua":40,"teal":43,"lightblue":48,"blue":60,"indigo":67,"purple":66,"royalpurple":65,"magenta":61,"pink":60,"dustypink":60,"red":60},"dark":{"orange":48,"gold":44,"yellow":40,"chartreuse":35,"green":36,"forest":30,"aqua":32,"teal":36,"lightblue":39,"blue":53,"indigo":59,"purple":58,"royalpurple":56,"magenta":49,"pink":51,"dustypink":50,"red":51},"evendarker":{"orange":40,"gold":37,"yellow":33,"chartreuse":27,"green":29,"forest":24,"aqua":26,"teal":31,"lightblue":32,"blue":48,"indigo":51,"purple":50,"royalpurple":47,"magenta":40,"pink":42,"dustypink":41,"red":42},"ultradark":{"orange":34,"gold":31,"yellow":29,"chartreuse":23,"green":24,"forest":20,"aqua":22,"teal":27,"lightblue":27,"blue":40,"indigo":41,"purple":42,"royalpurple":39,"magenta":33,"pink":35,"dustypink":35,"red":35},"almostblack":{"orange":28,"gold":26,"yellow":26,"chartreuse":20,"green":20,"forest":16,"aqua":19,"teal":24,"lightblue":24,"blue":33,"indigo":34,"purple":35,"royalpurple":32,"magenta":28,"pink":30,"dustypink":30,"red":31}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you only need to do a `countourf`:

```
plt.contourf(df, cmap='RdYlBu')
plt.xticks(range(df.shape[1]), df.columns, rotation=90)
plt.yticks(range(df.shape[0]), df.index)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Or a heatmap:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.heatmap(df, cmap='RdYlBu')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Gorgeous, thanks!